# Peugeot 207 timing chain

Tags: peugeot, timing-chain

Hi I'm going to look at a 207 1.6 diesel hdi tomorrow, after the head gasket went on my old rover.
The car's done 95000 miles and I know this is low for a diesel but it hasn't had a cambelt/timing chain change, the guy said it's because peugeot said it should be done at 120,000 miles which seems to be true, they do recommend this however it seems like a bit much to me. I was wondering if anyone had any advice about this?

Answer (score 1):

The Peugeot HDI engine has a cambelt and usually takes around 3hours to do a cam belt and water pump.

The water pump is driven of the cam belt and I would always replace the water pump at this millage at the same time as the belt for two reasons; it only takes a extra few minutes as you have to remove the cam belt to get to the pump and costs very little so you can call this preventative maintenance, if the water pump bearing fails or seizes it will do the same amount of damage as the cambelt snapping.

I would always recommend replacing the cambelt at every 60,000 miles or every 6 years.

120,000 does seem very high and I personally wouldn't like to leave it that long especially as the HDI is an interference engine meaning massive damage if it fails. Of all of the cambelt failures I have dealt with age has been the issue over time they 'rot' and the teeth strip.

So as a precautionary measure I would replace the belt and water pump, then from then on the belt at 60,000miles (or 6 years) and the water pump every other belt change (so every 120,000 miles).